# Why resized function is always trigger when resizing browser window. even if there is no dependency in useEffcet?

Tags: reactjs

```html
 const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)


function resized () {
    
    setInner(window.innerWidth)
  }

 useEffect(()=>{
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', resized)

    return () => {
      
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resized)
    }
 }, [])
```

There is no dependency set in useEffect, meaning useEffcet only triggers when page load. Resized function is inside the useEffect and it's only triggered when the page load. But this function has always trigger when we resized the browser window it supposes to be triggered only once.

Comment: you're adding an event listener to the resize event, which means that the function will be called every time the window is resized. this has nothing to do with useEffect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resized)
```

When you run this line of code, you are asking the browser to call `resized` every time there is a resize event. The empty dependency array only controls how often the useEffect runs, ie, how often you add and remove the event listener. But if you've added the listener, even once, you will then get an unlimited number of resize events from the browser.

If you only want to pay attention to the first time the event happens, you will need to add some code to remove the listener once it goes off once:

```
useEffect(() => {
  function resized () {    
    setInner(window.innerWidth)
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resized); // <---- added
  }
  window.addEventListener('resize', resized)

  return () => {      
    window.removeEventListener('resize', resized)
  }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

function resized() {
    setInner(window.innerWidth);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", resized);
}

useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", resized);
}, []);
```

Comment: I know this works. But I have doubt that if there is no dependency set in useEffect. So why resized function is called after page load whenever resizing the browser window?